# Modify existing query from an unrelated table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have this query:

SELECT * FROM COMPANY_INFORMATION, ADDRESS WHERE ADDRESS.ID = COMPANY_INFROMATION.ID;

That gets the address and company information from two tables.

In addition I have a table called REVIEWS that have 3 columns ID, RATING(int), REVIEW(TEXT).

Is it possible to modify the existing query to get the number of ratings and average ratings in one query call.

I know of the COUNT(*) and AVG(RATING) methods, but i don't want to make 2 or 3 SQL calls.

Thank you for any one that can help.

Comment: inner join the reviews table on id

Comment: I'm not familiar with joins.. where would that go exactly? @Trey

Comment: It looks strange that the id of an address is also the id of a Company Information record. Are these unique in both tables nonetheless? And the id in reviews is again the same id, but there can be more entries per id?

Comment: why is the address not in the company information table?

Comment: @user3032422 . . . If you do not know what a join is, then we do you no favors by helping with your query.  You need to learn basic SQL, just as you would learn the basics of any language in order to start using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT c.*, a.*, count(r.rating) as total, AVG(r.rating) as average
FROM COMPANY_INFORMATION c 
inner join ADDRESS a on a.id = c.id
inner join REVIEWS r on r.id = c.id
```